# PhD CV with not experience in academia job

Tags: phd, application, cv

after many years of working on telecommunications for various companies, I decided to change my career to Linguistics, and language technology. to do this I graduated from BA in Modern Languages and did a MA in Linguistics.  Just few weeks ago I saw and advert for a paid linguistics PhD position in The Netherlands. I have never contemplated the idea of pursuing a PhD, but the research project is very attractive to me.
So, I am working on my CV, however I don’t have papers published nor academia working experience.  and the only research I have undertaken was during my MA – assignments and dissertation.
I wonder if you can advise, how I can overcome the lack of academia -research experience in my CV?
Many thanks!
Sarita

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry too much - just apply (you cannot to much different things anyway). Most people have no real research experience before the phd. Phd is meant as learning how to research. So apply and good luck!